# prove at most one solution through implication

Tags: logic

From the formula $ 6\cdot x = 12 \Longrightarrow x = 2$ we can only say that $2$ is at most one solution.
From the implication i learnd i cannot get that $2$ is a solution nor that $2$ are all solutions. But i don't see why i cannot get that $2$ is a solution, how can it be that we cannot derive from the implication that there is a solution at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very meaning of

> $x=2$ is a solution of $6\cdot x=12$

is

> **IF** I plug in the value $2$ for $x$ in $6\cdot x=12$, **THEN** I obtain a true equality,

in other words "$x=2\implies 6\cdot x=12$", for which you would ultimately verify arithmetically that $6\cdot 2=12$.

Note that the arrow you need points in the exact opposite direction than the arrow you have.

Then again, multiplying both sides of an equation with a non-zero expression is an *equivalence transform*, i.e., if $c\ne 0$ then
$$ a=b\iff ca=cb$$
so that (if that is how you arrived at $6x=12\implies x=2$ in the first place) you could have written $\iff$ right away and could continue happily. As not *all* things you can do to an equation is really an equivalence transform, it is very important to keep track of those steps that are and those that are not (and thus one has to be diligent in the choice of $\implies$ vs. $\iff$ in ones derivation). Whenever one of your steps happens to not be an equivalence transform, the final statement gives you only *necessary* conditions and these may fail to be *sufficient* conditions for the solution.